# Reactjs: Remove Space between classnames for a div tag with multiple classnames

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Here the image is a boolean. In case the image is true and anotherclassName="anotherclassname". There is an extra space between someclass and someclass-anotherclassname

```
<div class = "someclass  someclass-anotherclassname">
```

How do I remove space between these classnames if image = true or if image = false and anotherclassName = " "?

```js
 
const baseClass = "someclass"
var c = prefix(baseClass);

  <div className={`${baseClass} ${c({ active: !image })} ${anotherclassName}`.trim()}
   <p>Brooklyn</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the possible classes into an array, then filter and join it.

```
className={
  [baseClass, c({ active: !image }), anotherclassName]
    .filter(Boolean)
    .join(' ')
}
```

Or put the possible classes at the beginning and the end, and trimming will get rid of the extra spacing.

```
className={`${anotherclassName} ${baseClass} ${c({ active: !image })}`.trim()}
```

Comment: But if anotherclassName is empty and image is false, even then there would be a space right?
anotherclassName: ""
image: false
<div class = "someclass  <space-here> someclass-active">

Comment: This is the first time you said that `anotherclassName` could be empty. If so, either use the code in the first part of the answer, or put the `anotherclassName` at the beginning instead of at the end.

Comment: Sorry, should've specified. Thank you very much, I will these solutions :)